# jquery input .focus on IOS iphone triggers a zoom and when type nothing happens

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, click, focus

The question is about jQuery and .focus() on a field when it's IOS / iPhone.

I have a ajax login with 2 fields user / password

```
<input type="text" onchange="ajaxToVerifyUser();"
<input type="password" id="password_input" onchange="ajaxpassverification(this.value)"
```

on the ajaxToVerifyUser once user exists : I echo `<script>$("#password_input").focus();</script>`

This works on desktop and android fine. **** but in IOS (iPhone) it's a total different story :(

it f$#@$ing full mega zoom on the field and when the user type, it's blank and the onchange receives no values. The user have to unzoom and touch the field for it to work.

I tried to change it to `<script>$("#password_input").click();` --> don't work :(

How can this be fixed ?

Reminder ; I'm looking for a fix for IOS only not a complete redo of my form.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try vanilla js? Like this: `document.getElementById("password_input").focus();`

Comment: No, stil the same behavior... when type the typing cursor goes away and don't type inside the input :(

Comment: is there an alternative to .focus() ?

Comment: No. I think there is no other way to help. So I think the main problem stems from the `ajaxpassverification`. If you wish, send that function to check its contents. Maybe by changing the algorithm of that function, we will achieve the desired result.